# How do I store the result of an eval statement in a variable?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, variables, eval

Given the following regex pattern, `pattern="\[Adjective]|\[Noun]|\[Adverb]"` and a string, `$lib` which will either be a regular word or a marker, such as `[Adjective]` or `[Noun]` I want to store the result of the substitution to a variable.

The statement

```
printf "%s" $l | sed -E 's/'$pattern'/'$lib'/'
```

performs the substitution just fine, but when I change that over to

```
eval foo=\$"l | sed -E s/'$pattern'/'$lib'/"
echo $foo
```

all I get is whitespace.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foo=$(printf "%s" $l | sed -E 's/'$pattern'/'$lib'/')
```